# openvz dual nic setup from scratch

Tags: openvz, nic

I have a openvz server that has 2 nics I need 1 for ethernet and the other explisitly for nfs traffic.

eth0 goes to the lan/internet currently doesnt have ipv6 but will be getting a static ip soon.
eth1 is the private nfs lan ipv6 is optonal for now.

venet0-00 is up on boot, it doesnt seem to be used though.

veth1.0 goes up when I turn a CT on.  neither have ipv4 addresses and I havent been able to match up what the docs and this system to enable trafic on eth1.

on the CT side it shows as venet
venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00                    -00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.                    255

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00                    -00
          inet addr:10.1.11.254  P-t-P:10.1.11.254  Bcast:10.1.11.254  Mask:255.255                    .255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

I would appriciate help sorting it out.  [OpenVZ multiple networks on CTs](https://serverfault.com/questions/133566/openvz-multiple-networks-on-cts) is basically what I want to do but im missing either how to create venet1 if its needed, or how they routed the trafic from the 2nd nic to the 2nd CT device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the ovz-web-pane when creating or editing the container you can put it as "10.1.1.1 10.1.2.1"   leaving a space in the ip listing will create two nics on the ct with seperate ip's

Comment: I had to add a iptables masquerade line in on the host to allow the 2nd ip to work normally.  I also had some ugly results when the 2nd ip was using nfs heavly trying to find some answers on that but thats a whole other mess.